# How can i create a section hero with tailwindcss and dynamic height

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I create a hero section (with dynamic height and inner a container) with tailwindcss like the screenshot/the codebox sample? The red section has to be full-screen width.

[image: hero section image sample]

1. [hero section codebox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-banzai-2oom7?file=/index.html)
2. [hero section tailwind sample](https://play.tailwindcss.com/CaBUK0i4Bd)
3. [here you can find the solution in bootstrap/cssm but I can't do it
   with tailwind](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/tVkNyWJxA6)
4. [and here is the solution with tailwind css](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mRgaj8Laow)
5. [and here you can get a full width hero with inner container](https://play.tailwindcss.com/7JF2W8rN3R)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information. I am assuming you need a height that adjusts itself according to the screen.

```
<div class="h-1/4">
Dynamic height according to screen height
</div>
```

Edit:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>tailwind section hero</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container relative mx-auto">
      <h1 class="text-7xl my-4">headline1</h1>
      <p class="text-2xl my-4">this is a text</p>
      <p class="text-2xl my-4">this is a text</p>
      <p class="text-2xl my-4">this is a text</p>
      <div class="w-screen bg-red-500">
        <h3 class="text-5xl">section hero</h3>
        <p>text...</p>
      </div>
      <p class="text-2xl my-4">this is a text</p>
      <p class="text-2xl my-4">this is a text</p>
      <p class="text-2xl my-4">this is a text</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**codepen link** : https://codepen.io/gouravthakur39/pen/mdWvNOq

Don't apply padding on the container itself.

Comment: If i'am looking at your codepen sample, the red section is not 100% width. It startet at the text, but it have to start from the left side of the screen.

Comment: I've added some more samples and a solution in boostrap/css.